# Package designer is missing from visual studio solution

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 having a SharePoint solution. Somehow, I was missing  the Package folder in the solution. I got it back from the Source Control Explorer as the solution is saved in to the TFS. But I am not able to open the Package file in the designer. As while deploying the solution I am getting an error `A Feature with the following item ID could not be found:[ID]`. This file is already deleted from solution but there is still reference lied in the pakcage file. When I remove it from the xml file, it is not getting deleted. So now, I need to open the package file in the designer and remove reference of that solution item.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching on internet for hours and with the help of Mr. Kalpesh (my superior)  I was able to find the solution.

There is one `.csproj` file for each solution. Open this in the notepad and find for the `<None Include="Package\Package.package">` tag. In my case it was not there. So I got another working solution's `.csproj` file and copied the entire tag from it.

```
<None Include="Package\Package.package">
  <PackageId>{GUID Of Solution}</PackageId>
</None>
```

> To get the solution id convert the `wsp` to `cab` and extract all files. In `manifest.xml` file you will find the solution id.

The same solution ID should be there in `Package.package` file in `Id` attribute and `solutionId` attribute of `package` tag.

After doing above changes I was able to open the Package file in designer and also able to deploy the solution.

Hope this can save time of others.!!!